# How to Deserialize JSON with JavaScriptSerializer to Tuples

Tags: c#, json, json.net, javascriptserializer

I'm looking way to Deserialize JSON string to c# `List<Tuple<string, string>>`.

```
    "[{\"name\":\"OkeyTablePaired\",\"value\":\"true\"},    
      {\"name\":\"OkeyTableIndicator\",\"value\":\"true\"},    
      {\"name\":\"OkeyTableHued\",\"value\":\"true\"},    
      {\"name\":\"OkeyTableSpectatorQuiet\",\"value\":\"true\"},    
      {\"name\":\"OkeyTableEveryoneQuiet\",\"value\":\"true\"}]"
```

Tuple List:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> tupleJson = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
```

I would like to put them together as

```
[OkeyTablePaired]:[true]
[OkeyTableIndicator]:[false]
[OkeyTableHued]:[true]
[OkeyTableSpectatorQuiet]:[true]
[OkeyTableEveryoneQuiet]:[true]
```

in the List Tuple...

Any help would be fantastic. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<T> ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.helpers.json.decode(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: That isn't a valid JSON string. Does it have array brackets (`[]`) around it perhaps?

Comment: i added expected tags to sample json code. i forgot to write. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Note that you need to convert the input to valid json array by adding brackets [] first. You will need to get [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to make this work.

```
        //using System;
        //using System.Collections.Generic;
        //using System.Linq;
        //using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

        string validJson = "[" + json + "]";
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(validJson);
        List<Tuple<string, string>> tupleJson = jsonArray
            .Select(p => new Tuple<string, string>((string)p["name"], (string)p["value"]))
            .ToList();
```

More info in the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithLinq.htm).

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll use this. it is very simple and really shord code! thanks a gain +1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get a valid JSON array, a custom converter with JSON.NET would work as well:

```
public class TupleConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<Tuple<string, string>>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> result = null;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {            
            JArray deserialized = JArray.Load(reader);
            result = new List<Tuple<string, string>>(deserialized.Count);

            foreach (var token in deserialized)
            {
                if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    result.Add(Tuple.Create(
                        token["name"].ToObject<string>(),
                        token["value"].ToObject<string>()));
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> result = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tuple<string, string>>>(json, new TupleConverter());
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEbNsH

Comment: +1, but I have a few suggested improvements: if the JSON fragment in the question happens to be part of a larger JSON containing more than just the list of key-value pairs, this converter will try to convert everything and fail, due to the fact that `CanConvert` always returns true.  It would be better if `CanConvert` only returned true when `objectType == List<Tuple<string,string>>`.  Also, you should implement `CanWrite` to return false if `WriteJson` isn't implemented.  `CanRead` returns true by default in the base JsonConverter, so you don't need to override that one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll make some changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you've created a data contract for Tuple that the JSON can interpret, you can use DataContractJsonSerializer (from the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json library):

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (Tuple));
var objResponse = (Tuple) jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
```

The data contract, in your case, would probably be pretty straightforward, something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Tuple
{
    [DataMember]
    public string OkeyTablePaired {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string OkeyTableIndicator {get; set;}
    .....etc.
}
```